# Any insight about this sequence of numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, functions

I don't have a background in math beyond high-school calculus and one course in discrete math. I was hoping you guys might be able to give me some information about the sequence of numbers generated by this rule:

For any positive integer s, start with n=0 and a=1.

Set a to 2a if s >= 2a. Otherwise, set a to 2 × (s - a) + 1. Add 1 to n. Repeat until a is 1 again.

The first few numbers (n) in the sequence (for s=1, 2, 3...) are 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 4, 4, 9, 6, 11, 10, 9, 14, 5, 5. The maximum value seems to be s and the minimum seems to be log2(s+1).

I'm looking for any information I can find about this sequence. Is there a general term for this type of function? Is there a concise way to express this rule as a sum or equation? Please point me toward any additional resources you think might be helpful, I'm not sure where to begin. Also feel free to format this question to make it more clear.

Comment: I think I have found your series: http://oeis.org/A003558

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are finding the least number $m$ such that $2^m \equiv \pm 1\mod 2n + 1$, where $n$ is the  entry in the sequence. See http://oeis.org/A003558.